# How to understand some bewildering limits of sequences of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(s_n)$ be the sequence of sets $s_n=\{n\}$ of natural numbers $1, 2, 3, ...$ Then the limit is the empty set $\{\}$. The sequences of sets $a_n=\{n^1\}$ or $b_n=\{n^n\}$ or $c_n=\{\frac{n}{1+n}\}$ have also empty limit sets. This shows that no natural number will remain in all sets of the sequence. All natural numbers will be exhausted.

But this simple argument appears to fail in cases like $d_n=\{n^0\}$ or $e_n=\{\frac{n}{n}\}$ or $f_n=\{\frac{n}{0+n}\}$? Of course all these limits are $\{1\}$. But why don't the natural numbers get exhausted in these cases too?

Or consider the even more complicated cases involving sets of pairs $g_n=\{(1,n)\}$ or $h_n=\{1_n\}$ or $i_n=\{x_n\}$ (where $n$ is an index). Can they disappear partially?

Comment: Previously asked at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/172790/why-do-the-natural-numbers-get-exhausted-in-some-limits-but-not-in-all (but closed there as off-topic).

Comment: Yes, there has no answer been available, unfortunately.

Comment: "why don't the natural numbers get exhausted in these cases too?" Why should they? Why should writing $1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\dots$ exhaust the natural numbers? I'm really having trouble understanding what is giving you trouble here.

Comment: I am only asking. I don't know why the natural numbers should get exhausted at all. But the well-known definition leads to this result in some cases, if the limit is understood as the set after all finite steps. Trouble is given in the last paragraph concerning pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused between what the sets in the sequences *are* and how you happen to have *described* them.

When you write $s_n=\{n\}$, this is neither more nor less than a succinct description of the sequence
$$ (s_n)_n = (\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\ldots)$$
Because there is no element that is in more than one of these sets (much less in all of them from some point), there can be no element of the limit set.

Similarly,
$$ (a_n)_n = (\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\ldots)$$
$$ (b_n)_n = (\{1\},\{4\},\{27\},\{256\},\{3125\},\ldots)$$
$$ (c_n)_n = (\{\tfrac12\},\{\tfrac23\},\{\tfrac34\},\{\tfrac45\},\{\tfrac56\},\ldots)$$
$$ (d_n)_n = (\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\ldots)$$
$$ (e_n)_n = (\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\ldots)$$
$$ (f_n)_n = (\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\ldots)$$

Each element of the $d_n$ , $e_n$ and $f_n$ sequence is *the same set*, even though you have produced it by slightly different *calculations*. Once the sequence is defined, it doesn't matter *how* you defined it, only what the *results* of that definition is. There is only one $\{1\}$, and it doesn't know how you arrived at it.

In each of these three cases you get a *constant* sequence of sets, with the common element as its limit.

I'm not even sure what you mean by "$1_n$" for the $h$ sequence. And $g_n=\{x_n\}$ will converge to a singleton set exactly if $(x_n)_n$ is constant from some point, or will not converge if infinitely many $x_n$s (but not all of them from some point) are equal, or to the empty set otherwise.

Comment: The question in paragraph 2 reads in greater detail: 1 can be written as n/n. Nobody can force me to write 1. Both notations. are always identical. Why does this sequence not exhaust the natural numbers used? $g_n$ is a sequence of pairs of numbers. (They could also be pairs of singletons.) The first number is a constant, the second number is not. What about that limit?

Comment: @Bacarra: You're not forced to write $1$, but you're not _allowed_ to conclude that two things are different just because you choose to write them in different, equivalent, ways. Your idea of "exhaust the natural numbers used" seems to be so badly misunderstood that you'd better just forget it and start over.

Comment: Do you not believe that the natural numbers can be exhausted? You seemed to argue in favour of that idea. But it does not matter how we call it. Assume that the first two paragraphs are correct, then the question rises what are the limits of the sequences of pairs of the third paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

So maybe the problem is in understanding the definition of the limit of a sequence of sets. Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ be a sequence of sets. The definition I propose to use for $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ is that it consists of those $x$ that are in every $A_n$ from some point on; that is, it is those $x$ such that there is an $m$ such that $x$ is in $A_m,A_{m+1},A_{m+2},\dots$. [If this is not your definition of the limit of a sequence of sets, then please let us know what exactly your definition is.]

Now with this definition, the sequences 
$$\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\dots\\ \{1^1\},\{2^2\},\{3^3\},\dots\\ \{1/2\},\{2/3\},\{3/4\},\dots$$ all have limit the empty set, since there is no $x$ that is in all the sets from some point on.

The sequence $$\{1^0\},\{2^0\},\{3^0\},\dots=\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\dots$$ has limit $\{1\}$, since $1$ is in every one of those sets (and is the only number in each set from some point on). Similarly, $$\{1/1\},\{2/2\},\{3/3\},\dots=\{1\},\{1\},\{1\},\dots$$ has limit $\{1\}$, it's the same sequence as the previous one. Same is true for $$\{1/(0+1)\},\{2/(0+2)\},\{3/(0+3)\}\dots$$ as it's the same sequence as the previous two. I have no idea what you mean when you say these sequences "exhaust the natural numbers".

The limit of $$\{(1,1)\},\{(1,2)\},\{(1,3)\},\dots$$ is again empty, since there is no pair $(x,y)$ that is in all of these sets from some point on.

Comment: According to your last statement the limit of ${\{1_n}\}$ (just a 1 with a natural index) will be empty, if $1_n$ is understood as a pair but will be $\{1\}$ if not understood as a pair. Have I understood you right?

Comment: I don't understand how to understand $1_n$, as a pair or as anything else. I don't understand how you index the number one.

Comment: We can index every term, be it x or 1. For instance we have the first 1 in the decimal expansion of some real number, then the second 1, and so on. They differ in position but they are equal in size. `The indices are different in size of course. What is the criterion for calculating the "limit"?

Comment: So you are talking about the sequence, the set consisting of the first 1 in the decimal expansion of $9/11$, the set consisting of the second 1 in the decimal expansion of $9/11$, the set consisting of the third 1 in the decimal expansion of $9/11$, and so on. My gut reaction is that this is such a silly sequence no one could be bothered to try to figure out what its limit is, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The 1's could appear in the binary expansion of $pi$ for instance. That would be interesting. But here my interest is focused on my question. Even mathematics without direct application can be interesting.

Comment: My gut reaction is that changing from base 10 to binary, and from $9/11$ to $\pi$, does nothing to decrease the silliness of the sequence.

Comment: Silly, because you have no answer? A scientist would be interested in such questions.

Comment: Do you have a proof of that? A proof even that there exists a scientist who would be interested in such questions, much less a proof that every scientist would be interested in such questions? I, for one, am willing to admit the possibility that somewhere there is a scientist who is interested in such questions, and I hope you find that scientist.

Comment: What is $1_n$ supposed to be? A number? If so, we should be able to do with it what can be done with numbers, such as perform addition. What is $1_n+1_m$ supposed to be? $2_k$ for some $k$?

Comment: Why do we need to know what $1_n$ is? It could be the $n$-th digit of the decimal representation of $\pi$. It could be a pair of coordinates. It could be something else. Symbolic mathematics should not depend on the intended meaning of its symbols. Does the differential quotient in calculus depend on the meaning of $x$ as a length or a pressure or a temparature?

Comment: I've decided the question isn't really about limits. Let $A_1$ be the set consisting of the first 1 in the binary expansion of $\pi$, and let $A_2$ be the set consisting of the second 1 in the binary expansion of $\pi$. The real question is, are $A_1$ and $A_2$ the same set? If so, then the limit is $A_1$; if no, then the limit is empty. So what you really have to decide is whether or not $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the same set.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson So the limit of the sequence $\{\frac{n}{a+n}\}$ depends on $a$. The calculation can be done without fixing $a$. The limit is empty unless we decide $a=0$ then the limit is suddenly not empty. But only if we decide to use 1 instead of $\{\frac{n}{n}\}$. With respect to $1_n$ the indices $n$ *are* and remain different. Probably we are interested only in them? Is it possible to calculate the limit in set theory?  You see that here deeper problems have been touched than appears on first glance. Perhaps you wish to revise your precipitate verdict in MathOverflow?

Comment: Did you read my last comment? Limits are not the issue. This has nothing to do with limits. Forget limits! The question is whether $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the same set. Why don't you concentrate your efforts on that question?

Comment: Limits *are* the issue. Do not believe that your contrary "decision" has any power in mathematics. You should be ashamed that you dared to close a question in MO that you did not understand and do not understand.

Comment: No, I voted to close a question that you did not and do not understand.

Comment: Gerry, you fell to another version of the classic blunder "Wolfgang asks 'trick' questions". :\

Comment: @Asaf, Bacarra = WM? That troll poisoned the Usenet newsgroup sci.math for years.

Comment: The very same...